# Blender 2.97b add ons not showing in add on window

Tags: add-on

Blender 2.97b add ons not showing in add on window
[image]This has been going on for a while and I can't understand what happened. The Add on window is completely blank. I have uninstalled Blender several times and still nothing. My MACBOOK Pro doesn't have the problem nor does my PC. The MAC Pro tower which I have been using for Blender since 2013 is the one with the issue. I opened the package contents of the Blender App and all of the folders seem to be in the right place. Still I have absolutely NO ADD ONS in the screen. I have been using add ons for years but I haven't really had to lately because I have everything I need. Here is a shot of the add ons tab. [image]